# WordPress images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a WordPress theme and need to be able to change the images **on each page** outside the WP text editor. Can this be achived without plugins?
Many thanks for you help.

Comment: What are you asking specifically?  This is incredibly vague...

Answer (score 3):

You can use FTP Manager and replace old images with the new ones.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Nidzaaaa 
And apologies for not being more clear. I need to add this as an admin functionality, so that the clients can change the images whenever they want to.

Comment: I think there is no other way to use it without Plugin or FTP Manager.  
[CHECK THIS PLUGIN](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-archives/)

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you don't just want to use the featured image on a page? - you can create a different template for each page with its own image on. For example if your site has three pages, home, about and contact for example, in your themes folder, saving page.php as page-home.php, page-about.php and page-contact.php is one way to do it. - alternatively use different featured images on each page.

Comment: Thanks, Andi
I have different templates for the different pages but there are images in the header and sidebar with different formatting (borders, shadows, rounded corners, etc) that cannot be included in the WP editor. I was hoping to get advise on how to make it possible for the client to change the images in the header and the sidebar separately from the rest of the content. Any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well, if in your page template, you set the image to get the the featured image, and place it at the page header, then whatever the client changes the image to will appear on the page in theory?

Comment: Thanks, Andy but since all images have different formatting this wouldn't help unfortunately. Thanks again.